# use of import statement

Tags: go

I've been toying around Go for a couple of weeks now, so far so good.
Now I am writing a program splitted across different files like this:

```
.
|-- geometry
|   |-- cone
|   `-- cone.go
|-- main.go
|-- Makefile
```

the problem is i can't import cone.go in the main.go, the compiler doesn't find it.
Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a bit of reading, [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/ad6fff21620536c8/9cd5f0de160335ae?lnk=gst&q=import+package+makefile#9cd5f0de160335ae) has a lengthy discussion on the problem you're asking about.

Here's a short answer.

Import looks for package in $GOROOT/pkg (IIRC), it does not look in local directories. What you can do is make a seperate makefile for "geometry" using the go package makefile includes [(see here)](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) and then have your main makefile make the package and pass the `-I` to include the new package in ./geometry

Comment: i'm reading right now and it seems the right page to find answers.
in the meantime, i found that the use of gobuild http://code.google.com/p/gobuild/ resolved the problem, at least my simple configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From the [gc docs:](http://golang.org/cmd/gc/)

```
Flags:

-o file     
       output file, default 6.out for 6g, etc.
-e  normally the compiler quits after 10 errors; -e prints all errors
-I dir1 -I dir2     
       add dir1 and dir2 to the list of paths to check for imported packages
-N  disable optimization
-S  write assembly language text to standard output
-V  print the compiler version
```

Try adding `-I geometry` to your compiler options.

Comment: -I alone won't work, the package has to be compiled as a package before import can find it